# Python - Extracting files from a large (6GB+) zip file

Tags: python, compression, zlib, zip

I have a `Python` script where I need to extract the contents of a ZIP file. However, the zip file is over 6GB in size.

There is a lot of information about `zlib` and `zipfile` modules, however, I can't find a single approach that works in my case.
I have the code:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(fname, "r") as z:
        try:
            log.info("Extracting %s " %fname)
            head, tail = os.path.split(fname)
            z.extractall(folder + "/" + tail)
        except zipfile.BadZipfile:
            log.error("Bad Zip file")
        except zipfile.LargeZipFile:
            log.error("Zip file requires ZIP64 functionality but that has not been enabled (i.e., too large)")
        except zipfile.error:
            log.error("Error decompressing ZIP file")
```

I know that I need to set the `allowZip64` to `true` but I'm unsure of how to do this. Yet, even as is, the `LargeZipFile` exception is not thrown, but instead the `BadZipFile` exception is. I have no idea why.

Also, is this the best approach to handle extracting a 6GB zip archive???

Update:
Modifying the `BadZipfile` exception to this:

```
except zipfile.BadZipfile as inst:
        log.error("Bad Zip file")
        print type(inst)     # the exception instance
        print inst.args      # arguments stored in .args
        print inst
```

shows:

```
<class 'zipfile.BadZipfile'>
('Bad magic number for file header',)
```

Update #2:

The full traceback shows

```
BadZipfile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8d34a9f58f6a> in <module>()
      6     for member in z.infolist():
      7         print member.filename[-70:],
----> 8         f = z.open(member, 'r')
      9         size = 0
     10         while True:

/Users/brspurri/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/zipfile.pyc in open(self, name, mode, pwd)
    965             fheader = struct.unpack(structFileHeader, fheader)
    966             if fheader[_FH_SIGNATURE] != stringFileHeader:
--> 967                 raise BadZipfile("Bad magic number for file header")
    968 
    969             fname = zef_file.read(fheader[_FH_FILENAME_LENGTH])

BadZipfile: Bad magic number for file header
```

Running the code:

```
import sys
import zipfile

with open(zip_filename, 'rb') as zf:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, allowZip64=True)
    z.testzip()

doesn't output anything.
```

Comment: What Python version do you have, and how was it built? (If you just downloaded a binary Windows or Mac installer from Python.org, or used the Python that came with your OS or installed a package from your distro, etc., just tell us exactly which one you're using; you don't need to figure out how Apple built the Python that came with OS X 10.9 or anything.)

Comment: @abarnert when I run `Python -V` I see: `Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)` So it's prebuilt somehow...

Comment: Also, instead of catching the `BadZipFile` and logging a generic string, can you show us the actual exception message and traceback? Then it will be obvious where and why it failed (e.g., from a quick look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/zipfile.py)) instead of having to guess.

Comment: OK, that means you got Python as part of Anaconda. We still might need to know what platform you're on, but that might be enough.

Comment: Anyway, the way to set `allowZip64` to `True` is the same way you pass any other keyword argument: `with zipfile.ZipFile(fname, "r", allowZip64=True) as z:`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @abarnert I updated the post to show more info about the exception. Not sure how to get a full traceback. Also I'm using OSX 10.8 (forgot to mention that).

Comment: You can get the traceback with the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) library. But a much easier way to do it is to just run the code outside a `try`/`except`. The unhandled exception will then just print out the traceback and quit your program immediately.

Comment: @abarnert I added the allowZip64, but no improvement.

Comment: A few more things to try: (1) See what `z.testzip()` returns. (2) Make sure the command-line `zip` tool (both testing with `-T` and just extracting) shows no warnings. (3) Run [this code](http://pastebin.com/ab3JjsHW), which should hopefully fail at exactly the same place as your code, but it will show us (a) which member it failed on, and (b) the full exception traceback.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the snippet. I updated the original post to show the traceback. It appears to be failing on the open?

Comment: Ahhh....`unzip file.zip` states `warning [file.zip]:  4294967296 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4294967296
  (attempting to re-compensate)
  inflating: file1             
  inflating: file2         
  inflating: file3` It still extracts the files alright though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have a corrupted zip file. I can add more details about the corruption below, but first the practical stuff:

You can use [this code snippet](http://pastebin.com/ab3JjsHW) to tell you which member within the archive is corrupted. However, `print z.testzip()` would already tell you the same thing. And `zip -T` or `unzip` on the command line should also give you that info with the appropriate verbosity.

---

So, what do you do about it?

Well, obviously, if you can get an uncorrupted copy of the file, do that.

If not, if you want to just skip over the bad file and extract everything else, that's pretty easy—mostly the same code as the snippet linked above:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as zf:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, allowZip64=True)
    for member in z.infolist():
        try:
            z.extract(member)
        except zipfile.error as e:
            # log the error, the member.filename, whatever
```

---

The `Bad magic number for file header` exception message means that `zipfile` was able to successfully open the zipfile, parse its directory, find the information for a member, seek to that member within the archive, and read the header of that member—all of which means you probably have no zip64-related problems here. However, when it read that header, it did not have the expected "magic" signature of `PK\003\004`. That means the archive is corrupted.

The fact that the corruption happens to be at exactly 4294967296 implies very strongly that you had a 64-bit problem somewhere along the chain, because that's exactly 2**32.

---

The command-line `zip`/`unzip` tool has some workarounds to deal with common causes of corruption that lead to problems like this. it looks like those workarounds may be working for this archive, given that you get a warning, but all of the files are apparently recovered. Python's `zipfile` library does not have those workarounds, and I doubt you want to write your own `zip`-handling code yourself…

However, that does open the door for two more possibilities:

First, `zip` might be able to *repair* the zipfile for you, using the `-F` of `-FF` flag. (Read the manpage, or `zip -h`, or ask at a site like SuperUser if you need help with that.)

And if all else fails, you can run the `unzip` tool from Python, instead of using `zipfile`, like this:

```
subprocess.check_output(['unzip', fname])
```

That gives you a lot less flexibility and power than the `zipfile` module, of course—but you're not using any of that flexibility anyway; you're just calling `extractall`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works perfect, and gives me full control over logging the correct portions. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Brett: See the edited version for some more ideas. But if you're happy with skipping the bad file, that's good enough.

Comment: Super useful information. I'd give you two checkmarks if I could. Thanks again.

Comment: Worked for me with the zip file of size 40gb (SynthText image dataset)