# Can't unzip zip file

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, zip

I'm trying to unzip a zip file inside my script using Python's `zipfile` module. The problem is that when I try to unzip this file, it raises `Bad magic number for file header error`:

This is the `error`:

```
..
  zip_ref.extractall(destination_to_unzip_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1040, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1028, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1082, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 971, in open
    raise BadZipfile("Bad magic number for file header")
zipfile.BadZipfile: Bad magic number for file header
```

The file I want to unzip is downloaded this way:

```
_url = """http://edane.drsr.sk/report/ds_dphs_csv.zip"""

def download_platici_dph(self):
    if os.path.isfile(_destination_for_downloads+'platici_dph.zip'):
        os.remove(_destination_for_downloads+'platici_dph.zip')
    with open(_destination_for_downloads+'platici_dph.zip','w') as f:
        response = requests.get(_url,stream=True)
        if not response.ok:
            print 'Something went wrong'
            return False
        else:
            for block in response.iter_content(1024):
                f.write(block)
```

Do anybody knows where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried unzipping the file using another utility to make sure it is a valid ZIP file?

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes, I've tried and it worked. The problem was with downloading the file as Rob said in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation for `open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open): "*when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value to open the file in binary mode*"

Open your output file using `b` for binary:

```
with open(_destination_for_downloads+'platici_dph.zip','wb') as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried downloading your archive without using your download-code and then extracting it with:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("ds_dphs_csv.zip") as a:
        a.extractall()
```

It worked fine. The exception **zipfile.BadZipfile** is raised when there is a problem in a header thus I think your file is corrupted after download. There must be a problem with your downloading method.

You can find more details on the exception in this post: [Python - Extracting files from a large (6GB+) zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890950/python-extracting-files-from-a-large-6gb-zip-file)